# What to do when answers contradict each other but have same votes?

Tags: discussion, answers

In a question I asked on [networkengineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12517/what-is-nodal-delay/12558#12558) the two answers given seem to contradict each other: one says "The nodal delay is the sum of all latency delays" and the other says it is separate "from delay caused by circuit length (distance/speed of light in fiber, etc.)". Both have +1 votes. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: You could try a bounty now it's two days old, that should attract attention especially when there aren't any featured questions at the moment.

Comment: Now one answer is at +3 and the other at +1, the better answer will eventually float to the top.

Comment: [it could be worse](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mOFCT.png)